# Adding toolbox items as parameters

Tags: c#

Hi I'm writing a program that IO from databses and I have the following function to read from the database and adds the rows to a combobox:

```
private void loadFromTuzel()
    {
        string constring = "Server=localhost;Database=ozturk;Uid=____;pwd=_____";
        MySqlConnection newCon = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        string selectCommand = "SELECT * FROM ozturk.tuzelkisi";

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(selectCommand, newCon);

        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        newCon.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader.Read())
        {

            cbselected.Items.Add(myReader["name"].ToString() + " " + myReader["Surname"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

as can be seen from the code the program loads the data from database to the combobox...

I need to use this function in a different form but need to load the data to a different combo box and I'm wondering if adding a toolbox item as a parameter to my function is possible so that it would be something like this

```
private void myfunction(thecombobox parameter comes here)
{
  // The execution code and than
  // thecomboboxparameter.items.add......
}
```

so I can use this function over and over at different forms just by adding the parameter value, is something like this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you'd be much better suited by moving that logic outside of your UI code altogether, and just return the items from the database. Don't pass the ComboBox to a parameter, but get the results from that method, and in your UI then tie everything together.

This is the basis of Separation of Concerns. Your ComboBoxes shouldn't care where the data comes from. They only care that they have data to display.

For the simple answer to your question, just adjust your method like this:

```
public static class Utilities 
{
    public static void loadFromTuzel(ComboBox cbo)
    {
        /// All of you other logic
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            cbo.Items.Add(myReader["name"].ToString() + " " + 
                myReader["Surname"].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

If you follow SoC, then you'd have something like this:

```
public class Repository {
    public IEnumerable<string> GetNamesFromTuzel()
    {
        // All of the same logic
        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            yield return myReader["name"].ToString() + " " + 
                myReader["Surname"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```